# Should I release / promote managed 2nd generation before security review or after security review?

Tags: security-review, release

Should I release / promote managed 2nd generation before security review or after security review? I am ready for security review but I am confused if I should use the beta versions that I have been testing or a released version.

If there are changes to be made after security review, and if it is release version do we publish  / release each time with updates?

Comment: You can use a beta release for your security review scans and submission. If changes are required, just create a new beta for rescan and resubmission.

Comment: BTW, once you have passed SR you can create as many new versions as you like until the next time a security review is requested. You will need to do an SR submission each time you want to select a new version for your app exchange listing, but these submissions are auto-approved unless and until the point where the Salesforce security review team ask for a submission.